# how to show previousmonth dates in calender

Tags: android

this is my cCalender code below is work fine but only problem is is not display date before first day of month see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzcV9.jpg and after lastday of month  full source code is here  https://www.zeta-uploader.com/1699876023

```
              i want to do something like this

           Sun Mon Tues  Wed  Thur Fri  Sat 
            29  30  31   1      2   3    4


        public class HoyahCalendar extends Activity {
public static int mYear;
public static int currentIndex = -1;
public static int mMonth;
public static int mDay;
public static String[][] a = new String[6][7];


        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);




                  last_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mMonth == 1) {
                mYear -= 1;
                mMonth = 12;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "last");
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                // mMonth -= 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "last");
                showOnScreen();
            }
        }
    });

    next_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 12) {
                mYear += 1;
                mMonth = 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "next");
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 4) {
                    HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = 4;
                    // mMonth += 1;
                }

                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "next");
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
    showOnScreen();





                  public class ShowCalendar {
int mYear;
int mMonth;
int mDay;
public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;
    calculateMonthFirstday();
}
public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;
    HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = 0;

    this.mDay = mDay;
    calculateMonthFirstday();
}


public int getmDay() {
    return mDay;
}





public void setmDay(int mDay) {
    this.mDay = mDay;
}





public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay, String time){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;
    if (time == "next"){
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
        if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 5){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
        }
        this.mDay = mDay + 7;
    } else if (time == "last"){
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
        if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
        }
        this.mDay = mDay - 7;
    }
    calculateMonthFirstday();
}

public void calculateMonthFirstday(){
    int month, first_day=0;
    if((mYear%4==0 && mYear%100!=0)||(mYear%400==0))
        month=1;
    else
        month=0;

    int y, y12, c, c12, m, d;
    y = mYear%100;
    y12 = (mYear-1)%100; //only for January and February
    c = mYear/100;
    c12 = (mYear-1)/100;
    m = mMonth;
    d = 1;

    switch(mMonth){
    case 1: {first_day = y12 + y12/4 +c12/4 - 2*c12 + 26*(13 + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 2: {first_day = y12 + y12/4 +c12/4 - 2*c12 + 26*(14 + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 3: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 4: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 5: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 6: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 7: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 8: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 9: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 10: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 11: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 12: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    }
    if(first_day<0)
        first_day = 7 - (Math.abs(first_day))%7;//first_day每月第一天星期几
    else
        first_day = first_day%7;

    switch(mMonth){
        case 1: {CalculateCalendar(1,first_day,31);break;}
        case 2: {CalculateCalendar(2,first_day,28+month);break;}
        case 3: {CalculateCalendar(3,first_day,31);break;}
        case 4: {CalculateCalendar(4,first_day,30);break;}
        case 5: {CalculateCalendar(5,first_day,31);break;}
        case 6: {CalculateCalendar(6,first_day,30);break;}
        case 7: {CalculateCalendar(7,first_day,31);break;}
        case 8: {CalculateCalendar(8,first_day,31);break;}
        case 9: {CalculateCalendar(9,first_day,30);break;}
        case 10:{CalculateCalendar(10,first_day,31);break;}
        case 11:{CalculateCalendar(11,first_day,30);break;}
        case 12:{CalculateCalendar(12,first_day,31);break;}
    }
}

public void CalculateCalendar(int month_no, int week_no, int month_days){

    int i, s = 0;
    int currentDay;
    if (this.mDay == 0){
        mDay = 1;
        currentDay= HoyahCalendar.mDay;     
    }else {
        currentDay = this.mDay;
    }
    //String[][] a = new String[6][7];
    for (i=0;i<week_no;i++)

        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = "";

    for(i=week_no; i<week_no + month_days; i++){
        s = i - week_no + 1;
        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = String.valueOf(s);
        if (s == currentDay && HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = i/7;
        }
    } 
    for (i=0; i<7;i++){
        if (HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i] == null){
            HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = "";
        }else{
            HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = 
     HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i];
        }

    }
    for(i=week_no+month_days; i<42; i++)


        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = "";
}
   }
```

Comment: please fix you source code link

Comment: ok w8 2 min  im fixin

Comment: check now   https://www.zeta-uploader.com/1699876023

Comment: Moh sukhni r u there? i update my source code link

Comment: Mon aukhni r u view my code??

Comment: i got you code, I'll have a look

Comment: if first date is on wednesday is show null on tuesday monday sunday i wantto display 31 30 29 on  sunday monday tuesday means calendernot show null

Comment: Moh suknni y u fixed the problem???

Comment: plz if u solve problem mail me on smartguy12000@gmail.com   is to late here i have to leave now

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for your problem. 
First you need a different design of the function that calculate the month calendar as array of 6x7
so use this function that takes year and month as parameters, then it will generate an accurate array of month calendar.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param year the year
 * @param month January=0, Feb = 1, ...., Nov = 10, and Dec = 11, you know what I mean
 * @return
 */
private static int[][] getArrayCalendar(int year,int month)
{
    //VERY IMPORTANT
    //SUN = 1, MON = 2, TU = 3, ..., Fri = 6, Sat = 7 according to USA
    int[][] a = new int[6][7];
    int day = 1; //day must be always one
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int goBack = 1 - dayOfWeek;
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, goBack);


    System.out.println("SU\tMO\tTU\tWE\tTH\tFR\tSA");

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<a[0].length;j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            System.out.print(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            System.out.print("\t");
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    return a;
}
```

Example: 
getArrayCalendar(2013,4)// **May=4**, year= 2013
RESULT AS PRINTED:

```
SU  MO  TU  WE  TH  FR  SA
28  29  30  1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8   9   10  11  
12  13  14  15  16  17  18  
19  20  21  22  23  24  25  
26  27  28  29  30  31  1   
2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

**- Now the quick fix for the issue:
modify your ShowCalendar class as following:**

```
    package com.example.calender5example;

    import java.util.Calendar;

    public class ShowCalendar
    {

          int mYear;
        int mMonth;
        int mDay;

    public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth)
    {
        this.mYear = mYear;
        this.mMonth = mMonth;
        calculateMonthFirstday();
    }

    public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay)
    {
        this.mYear = mYear;
        this.mMonth = mMonth;
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = 0;

        this.mDay = mDay;
        calculateMonthFirstday();
    }

    public int getmDay()
    {
        return mDay;
    }

    public void setmDay(int mDay)
    {
        this.mDay = mDay;
    }

    public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay, String time)
    {
        this.mYear = mYear;
        this.mMonth = mMonth;
        if (time == "next")
        {
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
            if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 5)
            {
                HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
            }
            this.mDay = mDay + 7;
        }
        else if (time == "last")
        {
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
            if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1)
            {
                HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
            }
            this.mDay = mDay - 7;
        }
        calculateMonthFirstday();
    }

    public void calculateMonthFirstday()
    {
        int month, first_day = 0;
        if ((mYear % 4 == 0 && mYear % 100 != 0) || (mYear % 400 == 0))
            month = 1;
        else
            month = 0;

        int y, y12, c, c12, m, d;
        y = mYear % 100;
        y12 = (mYear - 1) % 100; // only for January and February
        c = mYear / 100;
        c12 = (mYear - 1) / 100;
        m = mMonth;
        d = 1;

        switch (mMonth)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            first_day = y12 + y12 / 4 + c12 / 4 - 2 * c12 + 26 * (13 + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            first_day = y12 + y12 / 4 + c12 / 4 - 2 * c12 + 26 * (14 + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            first_day = y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c + 26 * (m + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            first_day = y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c + 26 * (m + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            first_day = y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c + 26 * (m + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            first_day = y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c + 26 * (m + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            first_day = y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c + 26 * (m + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 8:
        {
            first_day = y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c + 26 * (m + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 9:
        {
            first_day = y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c + 26 * (m + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 10:
        {
            first_day = y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c + 26 * (m + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 11:
        {
            first_day = y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c + 26 * (m + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        case 12:
        {
            first_day = y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c + 26 * (m + 1) / 10 + d - 1;
            break;
        }
        }
        if (first_day < 0)
            first_day = 7 - (Math.abs(first_day)) % 7;// first_day每月第一天星期几
        else
            first_day = first_day % 7;

        switch (mMonth)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(1, first_day, 31);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(2, first_day, 28 + month);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(3, first_day, 31);
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(4, first_day, 30);
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(5, first_day, 31);
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(6, first_day, 30);
            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(7, first_day, 31);
            break;
        }
        case 8:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(8, first_day, 31);
            break;
        }
        case 9:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(9, first_day, 30);
            break;
        }
        case 10:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(10, first_day, 31);
            break;
        }
        case 11:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(11, first_day, 30);
            break;
        }
        case 12:
        {
            CalculateCalendar(12, first_day, 31);
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    public void CalculateCalendar(int month_no, int week_no, int month_days)
    {

        int i, s = 0;
        int currentDay;
        if (this.mDay == 0)
        {
            mDay = 1;
            currentDay = HoyahCalendar.mDay;
        }
        else
        {
            currentDay = this.mDay;
        }
        // String[][] a = new String[6][7];
        for (i = 0; i < week_no; i++)

            HoyahCalendar.a[i / 7][i % 7] = "";

        for (i = week_no; i < week_no + month_days; i++)
        {
            s = i - week_no + 1;
            HoyahCalendar.a[i / 7][i % 7] = String.valueOf(s);
            if (s == currentDay && HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1)
            {
                HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = i / 7;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i] == null)
            {
                HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = "";
            }
            else
            {
                HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i];
            }

        }
        for (i = week_no + month_days; i < 42; i++)

            HoyahCalendar.a[i / 7][i % 7] = "";
//my fix starts here, I don't want to miss with your code

        int a[][] = getArrayCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
        HoyahCalendar.a = toStringArray(a);// Here I replaced your array
    }

    private String[][] toStringArray(int[][] a)
    {
        String[][] array = new String[6][7];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = Integer.toString(a[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return array;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param year
     *            the year
     * @param month
     *            January=0, Feb = 1, ...., Nov = 10, and Dec = 11, you know
     *            what I mean
     * @return
     */
    private static int[][] getArrayCalendar(int year, int month)
    {
        // VERY IMPORTANT
        // SUN = 1, MON = 2, TU = 3, ..., Fri = 6, Sat = 7 according to USA
        int[][] a = new int[6][7];
        int day = 1; // day must be always one
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

        int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int goBack = 1 - dayOfWeek;
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, goBack);

        System.out.println("SU\tMO\tTU\tWE\tTH\tFR\tSA");

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++)
            {
                a[i][j] = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                System.out.print(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                System.out.print("\t");
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

now you can use the function to generate full monthely calendar for any (year,month) and using that to navigate through you UI.

Comment: im confuse how to implement ur code is not show current week lastweek which click on button

Comment: the problem is next week and last week refere to the same location in your array[6][7], which is alaway [0][x]

that's why i advised you to reconsider the design of your code to meet the new array[][].

Comment: im confuse WHAT SUGGESTION U GIVE

Comment: also you code show difrence according to ur code 1st may show on sat but in actual is show on wed

Comment: that's because you month is advanced by one

use this line instead


int a[][] = getArrayCalendar(mYear, mMonth-1);

Comment: where i pput this line? on nextweek buton click??

Comment: yes month is work now how i make fot nextweek annd  lastweek???  im not understanding  how reconsider design???

Comment: I'm gonna help you with this, but first give me once I become free.